# What is the latest 32-bit LibreOffice version?

Tags: 18.04, libreoffice, 32-bit

While maintaining an ancient and honorable 32-bit Acer D250 running Ubuntu 18.04 (since that is the last 32-bit Ubuntu, AFAIK), I noticed it had LibreOffice 6.0 installed. In an effort to update to 6.2, [which was billed as the last 32-bit version](https://itsfoss.com/libreoffice-drops-32-bit-support/), I added the [LibreOffice/old-still ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Elibreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/old-still) and updated.

The update worked... but now I have LibreOffice version *7.3.7.2* running happily (*Calc*, *Impress*, and *Writer* are were used) on this machine with Intel® Atom™ CPU N270 CPU. Wonderful! Has the LibreOffice Foundation relented, continuing to support 32-bit machines, and for how long might this support continue? Or is this netbook running a 64-bit app ;-) ?

[image: LibreOffice 7.3.7.2]

In any event,**Thank you to LibreOffice for continued support!**

Comment: Looks like you're using [a back-port release](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libreoffice), which is part of the Universe repositories. Given that 18.04 is a matter of weeks away from going EOL, this could be one of the last releases your little netbook recieves 

Comment: Your netbook can continue to live using Debian, which still releases 32-bit. Ubuntu 32-bit was doomed merely by a lack of volunteers to test and support it; it could be resurrected if volunteers step up to do the work.

Comment: As @user535733 suggested, you can use Debian; the latest version on Debian is **7.0.4-4+deb11u4 i386**, while the latest version on Ubuntu 18.04 is **6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.12**.

Comment: @user535733, thanks for suggesting Debian OS upgrades. It's a shame to discard working hardware, and risky using it without at least security patches.